# Link Netsuite Saved Search to Custom Field on Sales Order

Tags: search, field, formula, netsuite

I am trying to create 2 custom fields on a Sales Order; to show the total number of items that are unfulfilled, and the total combined $ amount of those items.
I have been searching for awhile and the only help I could find is that this should be possible with a saved search.
So, I have created a saved search; 
[image: Saved Search Criteria]

[image: Saved Search Results]

[image: Saved Search Filter]

And I have created a custom transaction field (see below) which I believe is referencing my saved search, but how do I select which value it refers to? The field underneath where I selected my saved search BACKORDERS SUMMARY, doesn't appear to be related at all.

[image: Custom Field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Field` dropdown below the `Search` is **not** for selecting from the search results field.  Summary Searches provide 1 summary value only.  If you want 2 different values, you need 2 different searches.

The `Field` dropdown is used to select the field from the current record to use as the *filter* for the saved search.  Assuming your custom fields are placed on the Sales Order, you'll want to set your `Available Filters` criteria to `Internal ID` and leave the `Field` dropdown on the custom summary search field blank. (ie: just select your search from the `Search` dropdown. NS will pass in the internal id when the record is loaded.)

Try splitting your Backorders Summary search into 2 different searches, each with a single summary result type, update the filters, and set the `Search` drop downs to the appropriate values.  Should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Shea
Exactly what I needed!